# compare specific column values between two dataframes in R

Tags: r, compare

i have two data frames df1 and df2 where i want to compare values in a specific column present in both dataframes. How do i get the deisred output mention below in any format such a string or tibble or dataframe. Please note there will be duplicates in both data frames

```
df1 <- data.frame (channel= c("BNN", "BBC", "ABC" ,"SKY"),
                  second_column = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3","value_4")
                  )

df2 <- data.frame (channel= c("CNN", "BBC", "ABC"),
                  second_column = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3")
                  )
```

Desired output will be based on df2

Missing values in df2 : SKY,BNN

New values in df2 : CNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setdiff(x,y)` to identify the values in `x` that are not present in `y`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame (channel= c("BNN", "BBC", "ABC" ,"SKY"),
                   second_column = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3","value_4")
)

df2 <- data.frame (channel= c("CNN", "BBC", "ABC"),
                   second_column = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3")
)

list(
"Missing in df2" = setdiff(df1$channel, df2$channel), 
"New in df2" = setdiff(df2$channel, df1$channel))
#> $`Missing in df2`
#> [1] "BNN" "SKY"
#> 
#> $`New in df2`
#> [1] "CNN"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the packages **compareDF** or **dataCompareR**.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  channel= c("BNN", "BBC", "ABC" ,"SKY"),
  second_column = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3","value_4")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  channel= c("CNN", "BBC", "ABC"),
  second_column = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3")
)

# compare with 'compareDF' ####
library(compareDF)
comp <- compare_df(df1, df2)

create_output_table(comp)
```

[image]

```r
create_wide_output(comp)
#   rowname second_column_old second_column_new channel_old channel_new
# 1       1           value_1           value_1         CNN         BNN
# 2       4              <NA>           value_4        <NA>         SKY
```

```r
# compare with 'dataCompareR' ####
library(dataCompareR)
comp <- rCompare(df1, df2)
summary(comp)
# Data Comparison
# ===============
# 
# Date comparison run: 2023-09-26 15:55:12.575393  
# Comparison run on R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)  
# With dataCompareR version 0.1.4  
# 
# 
# Meta Summary
# ============
# 
# 
# |Dataset Name |Number of Rows |Number of Columns |
# |:------------|:--------------|:-----------------|
# |df1          |4              |2                 |
# |df2          |3              |2                 |
# 
# 
# Variable Summary
# ================
# 
# Number of columns in common: 2  
# Number of columns only in df1: 0  
# Number of columns only in df2: 0  
# Number of columns with a type mismatch: 0  
# No match key used, comparison is by row
# 
# 
# 
# Row Summary
# ===========
# 
# Total number of rows read from df1: 4  
# Total number of rows read from df2: 3    
# Number of rows in common: 3  
# Number of rows dropped from df1: 1  
# Number of rows dropped from  df2: 0  
# 
# 
# Data Values Comparison Summary
# ==============================
# 
# Number of columns compared with ALL rows equal: 1  
# Number of columns compared with SOME rows unequal: 1  
# Number of columns with missing value differences: 0  
# 
# Columns with all rows equal : SECOND_COLUMN
# 
# Summary of columns with some rows unequal: 
# 
# 
# 
# |Column  |Type (in df1) |Type (in df2) | # differences|Max difference | # NAs|
# |:-------|:-------------|:-------------|-------------:|:--------------|-----:|
# |CHANNEL |character     |character     |             1|NA             |     0|
# 
# 
# 
# Unequal column details
# ======================
# 
# 
# 
# #### Column -  CHANNEL
# 
# 
# 
# |   |CHANNEL (df1) |CHANNEL (df2) |Type (df1) |Type (df2) |Difference |
# |:--|:-------------|:-------------|:----------|:----------|:----------|
# |1  |BNN           |CNN           |character  |character  |           |
#
```

Comment: thanks for this but i did not want the whole output of all comparison just a comparison on the column names which the previous answer worked quite well